# PHP + C# Signer HASH

Tags: c#, php

I have two programs in C#, a server client to sign pdf files, the server prepares the files for signing and gives me a hash to sign.

Between the client and server programs it works without problems, the problem is that now I need to make a php routine to be the client

Server in c#

```
Stream data = appearance.GetRangeStream();
byte[] hashByte = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA1");
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashByte);
```

Client in c#

```
 public static string SignHash(string hash, X509Certificate2 cert)
 {           
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCert = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
 byte[] hashSigned = rsaCert.SignHash(Convert.FromBase64String(hash), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));               
 return Convert.ToBase64String(hashSigned);
            
}
```

in php

```
openssl_sign(base64_decode($hash), $sign, $private_key(), OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1)
```

the two applications in c# communicate over http in json, so it wouldn't be difficult to do it in php, the problem I'm facing is making the hash signature the same as in c#, so that I can save it in the pdf later

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Please provide input and expected output.

Comment: I believe the problem is in php in decoding and signing the hash that is compatible with C#

Comment: You believe? Again, please give a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm going to set up an example and upload it to github, but basically a signature using the same string and the same certificate, should have the same signature result

Comment: Please add all neccessary here, not on other platforms.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue, **here** in your question (or else it will be marked as off-topic see the [help/on-topic] for guidance). After that we should be able to help you. Thanks.